# Let $w = -\dfrac{1}{z}, E = \{z: |z - 1/2| = 1/4\}$. Find $w(E)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $w = -\dfrac{1}{z}, E = \{z: |z - 1/2| = 1/4\}$. Find $w(E)$.
The answer is the set of $w$ such that $|w + 8/3| = 4/3$. What I don't get is what my approach should be to solve this kind of problems without knowing the answer beforehand. I'm not posting what I've done because it's a simple problem and it's just a problem of right approach.

Comment: How much do you know about Möbius (linear fractional) transformations?

Comment: @HansLundmark I know the basics. I haven't practiced with them yet though.

Comment: So you know perhaps that circles (where in this context straight lines are counted as “circles with infinite radius”) are mapped to circles?

Comment: @HansLundmark yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward approach is to rearrange the transformation and substitute for $z$ in the locus to be transformed.

So you have $$z=-\frac1w\implies\left|-\frac1w-\frac12\right|=\frac14$$
$$\implies \left|\frac{2+w}{2w}\right|=\frac14$$
$$\implies2|w+2|=|w|$$

Now put $w=u+iv$ and get a Cartesian equation in $u$ and $v$ and you will get the equation of the circle you are expecting.

Can you finish?